# Basic HTML tag object blank lines problem

Tags: html, css, object

This is my code:

```
<body style="margin: 0px">

  <object data="Footer.html" width="100%" height="108px"></object>
  <object data="Footer.html" width="100%" height="108px"></object>
  <object data="Footer.html" width="100%" height="108px"></object>

</body>
```

And this is my output:

[image]

I have been hours trying to delete those blank lines between the object tags but I cant anymore. I have tried every possible tag or attribute but I simply dont know whats happening. The blank lines are on the bottom (the last one its not visible). If I inspect the HTML, the blank space doesn´t belong to any of the objects but the body. I have also tried to modify every attribute on the body like padding, margin, box, etc but it doesn´t seem to work. Thanks in advance for the anwsers.

Comment: vertical-align:top